# Android x86 change Keyboard layout

Tags: keyboard, android-x86

How can I change the keyboard layout used by Android from the command line?

I installed the Android-x86 release from https://www.android-x86.org/ in a VirtualBox VM. Unfortunately, the VM only boots to command line and I cannot access the GUI. I want to follow the following solution to directly boot into the GUI: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61247128/12336925

I cannot type the commands as I want and I cannot use vi appropriately because I have a German keyboard.